# Useless edits - removing "hello"

Tags: discussion, editing

Again ... Why do someone edit year old questions, just to remove "Hello"?

There are discussions about removing "thanks" lines from questions ... this is discussable, but removing "Hello" ...?

Saying "hello" is just polite ... absolutly disagree with such mass edits.

---

Update:

Dont want to start a new question ...

Recent topics shows 19 questions that were edited by Muhammad Anas - just to mark some words **bold** ... i love such improvements ...

No problem with small edits (to get some REP points), but please do something usefull.

- adjust tags
- check for newly created useless tags and replace them
- improve code formating
- ...

The problem aren't the "suggested" edits itself ... the reviews do a bad job in this cases and blindly approve everything.

Any ideas to improve this?

Comment: I agree on this.

Comment: 100% agree, few user doing extremely unnecessary edits!

Comment: I think he's doing just to get fake internet points ;)

Comment: and what about those who approves this type of edits from new users?

Comment: @Piyush agreed, reviewers should spent 1 minute or skip reviews. Why approve edits, that just mark some text as bold .... e.g. https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/220248/revisions

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 2):

Let them Edit all questions to make small improvements - 1 year old , 2 year old, 10 year old, but the main Problem is everytime someone edit , the **question display in Home page....**

**What i Suggest** :

1.If the Question has **Accepted answer**, then if whoever edit that question, it should not display in Home page....

2.If the Question asked before **3 months**, then if **someone** else Edit the question, then that question should not display in Home page.... If **OP** edit question, it should display in **home page**....

In this way we can keep the Home page clean.... It will help to increase the **Percentage of answers**....

Comment: I like the idea, BUT downside is that nobody could watch recent edits. "Let them edit all the questions" is no good idea at all :) Maybe a "clean" recent topics list with your suggestions as default and another with current results.

Comment: may be someone wants to watch `recent edits` , but i dont think it's required to see `all the edits` as the reviewer already checked the edits, `Let them edit all the questions` - > means whatever question need improvement - let them edit  all those questions.... yeah one more tab required : `clean recent topics/Unanswered edit questions` - so that many experts like you can target on that tab to help OPs......

Comment: You have given a good idea, I think you should add this one to new topic as development suggestion.

Comment: @ShoaibMunir Thanks, sure.... i ll add it soon....

Answer (score 2):

I am forever seeing pointless edits that seem to only be made for the sake of increasing badges or points. For example making the word product bold, the same person has done this many times today. A few edits:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/175826/revisions
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/175560/revisions
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/175651/revisions

The only solution I'm aware of is for people to be aware of this problem and not accept pointless edits.

Comment: All edits are approved by the same guys. This is a bit smelly ..... :(

Comment: Agreed, I can't see a way to report edits to grab mods attention

Comment: I have flagged this type of edits so many times for mods attention, Most of time they were marked helpful, but no idea if any action was taken or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with you also disagree.

stackexchange is Q&A platform not a discussion platform so it is not good formatting to add "Hello","Thanks".
This kind of words showing discussion then Q&A.

But remove those words to just earn point is also not good practice. So stackexchange should give option to approved edit without giving any point if there is not any major change in edit.

Comment: No, its not about reward points. He is already above 2k. It's about bumping old answered topics questions.